# how can get data in drop down list from data base in mvc3.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am designing a simple webpage using MVC3 in asp.net. I prepared a database using Sql Server, and i have attached this database in App_Data. There is a table employee in that database.

i want to get name of employee in a drop down list. so  i can select name of employee.

so please suggest me what will be model,view and controller code for accessing employee name in drop down list.

Comment: You really should check out http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ specifically http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66450#1400014

Answer (score 2):

I would start by designing a view model which will hold the data:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string SelectedEmployeeName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> employees = GetEmployeesFromDb();
        var model = new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            Employees = employees.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Name,
                Text = x.Name
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EmployeeViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("Selected employee name: " + model.SelectedEmployeeName, "text/plain");
    }
}
```

and finally the strongly typed view:

```
@model EmployeeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedEmployeeName,
        new SelectList(Model.Employees, "Value", "Text")
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. but i still have some confusions.  what is definition of method GetEmployeesFromDb(); in your above explanation and should i build a controller class named employees ?

Comment: @Pushpendra Kuntal, the `GetEmployeesFromDb` method is one that you should write and which will query the database and return of `Employee` models. You don't need another controller. You could define a repository class and put your data access logic inside this repository class. So the `GetEmployeesFromDb` would go into the repository.

Comment: Dear sir, please tell me how can i write query in repository class. your help will be grateful to me...

Comment: @Pushpendra Kuntal, read some tutorials and documentation, try it for yourself and if you encounter some difficulties don't hesitate to show what have you tried and I will be glad to help. http://asp.net/mvc is a good place to start learning. There is a section about implementing the repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a Method to populate the list from DB

2) Set a ViewModel to hold the List and selected value

//MODEL

```
 public List<SelectListItem> CategoriesSelectList()
            {

                var query = from c in _yourRepository.GetAll()
                            select c;

                List<SelectListItem> obj = new List<SelectListItem>();

                foreach (var item in query)
                {

                    var result = new SelectListItem();
                    result.Text = item.name;
                    result.Value = item.id.ToString();
                    obj.Add(result);

                }
                return obj;
            }
```

//VIEWMODEL

```
public class ViewModel
{
 [DisplayName("Category")]
        public int categoryId { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> CategoryList()
        {
            return new Model().CategoriesSelectList();
        }
}
```

//CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            //set the id for the VIEWMODEL property, if necesary
            var e = new ViewModel();
            e.categoryId = 1;//set the selected value

            return View(e);
        }
```

//VIEW

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.categoryId) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.categoryId,Model.CategoryList()) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.categoryId) %>
</div>
```